# How to keep the non mapped paragraphs during migrations?

Tags: 8, migrations, paragraphs

I am migrating content that contains paragraphs also. So I have two migration files.

When the content is migrated. Everything is fine. I can see the paragraphs are attached with the nodes.

When I edit a migrated node and adds a new paragraph to the node, then when I execute the migration again, that new paragraph removes from that node. Is there any way to keep them?

The paragraph_import.yml

```
langcode: en
status: true
id: paragraph_import
label: My paragraph import
migration_tags:
  - paragraph
source:
  plugin: csv
  delimiter: ','
  enclosure: '"'
  escape: '`'
  header_offset: 0
  ids: ['personal_number']
destination:
  plugin: 'entity_reference_revisions:paragraph'
  default_bundle: my_paragraph
process:
  mail:
    - plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: 'e-mail werk'
  cellphone:
    - plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: 'gsm werk'
  phone:
    - plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: telefoon
  langcode:
    - plugin: default_value
      default_value: 'nl'
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - migrate_source_csv
```

The node migration.

```
langcode: en
status: true
id: contact_import
label: Contacts
migration_tags:
  - node
source:
  plugin: csv
  delimiter: ','
  enclosure: '"'
  escape: '`'
  header_offset: 0
  ids: ['personal_number']
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: contact
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: contact
  title: title
  paragraph:
    - plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: paragraph_import
      source: personal_number
  my_paragraph_field:
    - plugin: sub_process
      source:
        - '@paragraph'
      process:
        target_id: '0'
        target_revision_id: '1'
  langcode:
    - plugin: default_value
      default_value: 'nl'
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - migrate_source_csv
```

My migration execute code.

```
$migration = $this->migrationPluginManager->createInstance($migration_id);
$migration->getIdMap()->prepareUpdate();
 try {
   $executable = new MigrateExecutable($migration, new MigrateMessage());
   $executable->import();
 }
 catch (MigrateException $exception) {
   $this->logger->error($exception->getMessage());
 }
```

It is different from [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/300878/how-to-preserve-the-values-of-paragraph-fields-in-migration) Because that question talks about the fields in the paragraph. While this question is about the paragraph entity itself.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as [How to preserve the values of paragraph fields in migration?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/300878/how-to-preserve-the-values-of-paragraph-fields-in-migration)?

Comment: That question was about the fields in the paragraph. This question is about the pargraph itself.

Comment: This is because you are overwriting/wiping the paragraph deltas most likely. This is moving a paragraph from A to B, its not preserving anything. I doubt there is a simple way to do that. A general rule of thumb is you cannot migrate content/data while also manually editing the same destinations.

Comment: @Kevin this makes sense. So if you are migrating content you cannot add it manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a custom source plugin for this to achieve.

Here is my source plugin code.

```
class MYSOURCECSV extends CSV {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepareRow(Row $row) {
    $database = \Drupal::database();
    $table = 'migrate_map_migration_id';

    // The migration removes the manually created entities from the system,
    // that are not present in the migration source. But we want them to be
    // ignored during the migration.
    if ($database->schema()->tableExists($table)) {
      $organisations = [];

      try {
        $results = $database->select($table, 'mmt')
          ->fields('mmt', ['destid1', 'destid2'])
          ->condition('sourceid1', $row->getSourceProperty('personal_number'))
          ->execute()
          ->fetchAll();

        if (!empty($results)) {
          foreach ($results as $result) {
            $paragraph_id = $result->destid1;

            $paragraph = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        

  ->getStorage('paragraph')
          ->load($paragraph_id);

        if ($paragraph instanceof ParagraphInterface) {
          $node = $paragraph->getParentEntity();

          // If paragraph is already attached to a node. Get the ids from
          // the node.
          if ($node instanceof NodeInterface) {
            $organisations = $node->get('my_paragraph_field')->getValue();

            if ($key = array_search($paragraph_id, array_column($paragraphs, 'target_id'))) {
              $paragraphs[$key]['target_revision_id'] = $result->destid2;
            }
          }
          else {
            $paragraphs[] = [
              'target_id' => $result->destid1,
              'target_revision_id' => $result->destid2,
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    }

    $row->setSourceProperty('my_paragraph_field', $paragraphs);
  }
  catch (Exception $exception) {
    \Drupal::logger('my_module')->error($exception->getMessage());
  }
}

parent::prepareRow($row);
  }

}
```

And then change the paragraph field mapping in the  migration file to:

```
my_paragraph_field:
    - plugin: sub_process
      source: organisations
      process:
        target_id: target_id
        target_revision_id: target_revision_id
```